# Add timepoint tooltip for an item with earned badge in the achivements dialog

Tags: feature-request, badges, tooltips, achievements-dialog, timestamps

If you cover reputation change in the achivements dialog by mouse pointer  - tooltip with timepoint will be shown:

> [image: rep]

For badge items no such behaviour exists:

> [image: badge]

If you want to know that date you need to find this badge in [the user profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/339911/alexolut?tab=badges), click on it and find one (because you can have many) with more suitable date (according to dates for nearest rep changes in the achivements dialog). It's a little bit tedious.

My request is to add tooltip with timepoint for earned badge items in the achivements dialog.